# infit load in dev mode with NextJS (_devPagesManifest.json fetch and 'includes' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am having some problems the last few days building my app in NextJS.

The problem is that at the start when running `npm run dev` everything works fin but after a few hot reload or manual page reloads its start loading forever and never responds afterwards.

The thing I could see is the dev tools is that it fetches `_devPagesManifest.json` and never gets an response. The only options is to restart the whole app. When restarting the app, sometimes I get a error message saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`.

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this? or has a fix for it because it makes developing so hard if I have to reload the app every few minutes.

My app is very basic and does not use a lot.

this is my packages.json if that helps

```
dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/jit": "^0.1.18",
    "@types/gtag.js": "0.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.2.9",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^6.2.3",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.1",
    "typescript": "4.0"
  }
```

Comment: I'm going through this now after upgrading to latest react and nextjs "Failed to fetch devPagesManifest SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" from page-loader.js and "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')" from router.js

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party here but this is one of the few search results that pop up for these search terms.

For people who encounter this and are using a reverse proxy to serve a nextjs app at a different path, the key knowledge here is that `.next/static/development/_devPagesManifest.json` is not a static file but is built at runtime and served by the Next.js App.

So if you have configured your proxy to serve files from `_next/static` and not to proxy to the actual nextjs server, you need to add a rule to pass requests for `devPagesManifest` to the nextjs server, if nginx (or whatever) tries to find the file in the `_static` folder it will not be there, but if it passes the request to Next.js it can handle it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you did this? What files and config values do I need to change/set in order to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible if using nginx:

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

```
location = /_next/static/development/_devPagesManifest.json {
     access_log        off;
     log_not_found     off;
     expires -1;
     proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000;
}
```

More details here:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16874